# Is it possible to use select with ncurses input?

Tags: linux, select, ncurses

Does ncurses use some file descriptors? Is it possible to use system call `select(int n, fd_set *, fd_set *, fd_set *, struct timeval *)` with ncurses library? If so how could I manage stdin in ncurses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When initializing, [`initscr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-initscr) uses *stdin* and *stdout*.  Using [`newterm`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-newterm) lets you use some other choice.  Internally, ncurses just uses the file descriptors for the corresponding streams.

A program using `select` would check if the file descriptor for *stdin* (or whatever input is used via `newterm`) and call `wgetch`, etc., when there is data ready.

If there's some concern about `wgetch` reading multiple bytes (and blocking too long), there are various options controlling how to [timeout](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html), etc.